# Access VBA DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet runs too slow and causes Run-time error

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a group of queries in a custom category in Access, and a bit of VBA code that gets the query names and runs them, and then copies the results for each query to a separate tab on an Excel spreadsheet. Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

Dim oExcel As Object
Dim oBook As Object
Dim oSheet As Object
Dim timestamp As String
Dim path As String

'Create the Excel spreadsheet
timestamp = Format(Now(), "yyyyMMddhhmmss")

path = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\ValidationResults" & timestamp & ".xlsx"

Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add
Set oSheet = oBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
oBook.SaveAs path
oExcel.Quit

'This gets a list of query names and puts it in a recordset
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("01 - GetValidationQueries")

'this runs each query and copies the results to a unique worksheet
Do While Not rs.EOF
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, rs("Name"), path, True, Left(rs("Name"), 2)
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

End Sub
```

The "01 - GetValidationQueries" query looks in the MSysNavPaneGroupToObjects and MSysNavPaneObjectIDs tables to get the names of the queries in a custom category.

The problem is that when I click the form button to run this code, I get the following error on the DoCmd line:

```
Run-time error '3275':
Unexpected error from external database driver (1309).
```

If I step thru the code line by line (hitting F8 each time) it runs fine, so I'm guessing the TransferSpreadsheet process is too slow. Other than putting a pause after that line, is there a better way of making this work?

EDIT: using the following code (for now, at least)

```
Public Function fnWait(intNrOfSeconds As Integer)
Dim varStart As Variant
  varStart = Timer
  Do While Timer < varStart + intNrOfSeconds
  Loop
End Function
```

Then before and after the DoCmd line, I have...

```
fnWait (2)
```

...to create a 2 second delay. It seems to be working so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this help you.

http://p2p.wrox.com/access-vba/24421-wait-function-vba.html

I did add it to my database so if you need help implementing it just ask.

Comment: Thanks .. I was looking at a few different timer solutions, but is putting a pause/wait/delay the best course of action?

Comment: That is what seem like the best solution to me since you need to let the code run. Also you can run a timer if you get the error so as to wait the minimum time possible.