# DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet triggering Error 3275 "unexpected error from external database driver"

Tags: ms-access, vba

A week ago, I build a form with a host of buttons to run queries between certain dates in my database, and then export those dates into an excel file. Over the past couple days, I expanded the capability to support custom file locations, sheet names, and source table names. I did all of this so that the tool is useable by whoever comes after me (I'm an intern).

About an hour ago, however, I started getting the error message `Run-time error '3275': unexpected error from database driver (1)` in a pop-up box. I can't upload pictures directly yet, but here is a [picture of the structure of my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3xaH.png). My code is below:

```
Private Sub SendToExcel_Click()
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "TBL_XL_DATA", _
    "X:\Confidential\Weekly Intel.xlsx", _ \\The file location is here in the actual code
        True, "Input"

End Sub
```

This is the 'default' export option, which I have not modified in any way over the past few days. The new function is as follows:

```
Private Sub CustomToExcel_Click()
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , [Forms]![Date Range]![SourceTable], _
    [Forms]![Date Range]![FileDest], _
        True, [Forms]![Date Range]![SheetName]
End Sub
```

I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017782/access-vba-docmd-transferspreadsheet-runs-too-slow-and-causes-run-time-error), with the same error, and using TransferSpreadsheet, but I don't think my problem is the command running too slowly, expecially considering I ran it (the newer command) an hour ago without trouble.

I am perplexed as to why the command doesn't work now, and why the unchanged command that I haven't dealt with in a while is also now throwing the same error. I am hoping someone understands enough about the error itself to give me a suggestion or two. What should I look for? What should I tinker with to get more information about it?

**Found the solution** in an obscure forum. My problem is that my path is too long for transferspreadsheet to handle. I am in luck, since my database and excel file are in the same folder. I am sure there is a way to have longer paths be supported, so if anyone knows how to do that, it would be appreciated. For now, I can at least work within the bounds of my constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't supplied the second argument of `TransferSpreadsheet` which is to specify they type of file that you are exporting to. You should supply this argument explicitly rather than relying on Access to provide it.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, etc..
```

for Excel 2007+ (saving as .xlsx).

You might include in your code a check of the file extension that the user has supplied (if any) so that you can use the corresponding spreadsheet-type enumeration.

The error that you received may have been because a file extension wasn't supplied.

**Added** `TransferSpreadsheet` accepts a maximum path-length of 64 characters. I would first attempt something simplistic like storing the fullpath in a variable and passing this variable to the method. This is unlikely to get around the limitation though.

Personally, I would transfer the spreadsheet to the temporary, or current, folder, perhaps:

```
Application.CurrentProject.Path
```

Then use a simple FileSystem Statement:

```
FileCopy source, destination
```

to copy the file, and finally:

```
Kill source
```

to delete the temporary version.

This seems a little long-winded but, personally, I like it. It offers me more control over the process. And it is necessary anyway, to get round the 64 character limit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll be testing it out today and I'll get back. This seems like the likely culprit, though I did ignore that argument in my initial execution, and it worked fine. I'm dealing with a much larger dataset now, which I think is contributing to my problem in some part. More details to come, along with an accepted answer, I hope.

Comment: And rectifying this has not changed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error is also being caused by recent Offices Patches:
see https://www.computerworld.com/article/3233260/microsoft-windows/excel-access-external-db-driver-errors-linked-to-this-month-s-patches.html
and [ODBC export to Excel fails under Windows 7, Windows 8.x and Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46706128/odbc-export-to-excel-fails-under-windows-7-windows-8-x-and-windows-10?noredirect=1#comment80459537_46706128)