# Importing excel files using CDatabase

Tags: excel, visual-c++, mfc, odbc, cdatabase

Early, I uses DAO to import excel files in MFC application, like this:

```
CDaoDatabase base1;
base1.Open(mfile, FALSE, FALSE, "Excel 5.0;");
```

After last windows updates this does not works. Is there correct way to import Excel files using ODBC (CDatabase class)?

Comment: Please tell us your error messages or your problems. This is a possible duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46706128/odbc-export-to-excel-fails-under-windows-7-windows-8-x-and-windows-10)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ODBC export to Excel fails under Windows 7, Windows 8.x and Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46706128/odbc-export-to-excel-fails-under-windows-7-windows-8-x-and-windows-10)