# MFC Problems about write a List Control to an Excel file

Tags: excel, mfc, listcontrol

I am writing a function which aims to wirte the content of a List Control to an Excel file. But I find the the format of the output is not as I wish. My code is

```
{
    CString buff0, buff1, buff2;
    CString fileName = _T("d:\\test.xls");//
    CFile file(fileName, CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeReadWrite | 
                   CFile::shareExclusive);
    file.Write("A\tB\tC\n", 56);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    j = m_list.GetItemCount();
    if (j > 0)
    {
        for (i = 0; i<j; i++)
        {
            buff0 = _T("0"); % only for test, should be m_list.GetItemText()
            buff1 = _T("1"); % for test
            buff2 = _T("2"); % for test
            CString msg;
            msg.Format(_T("%s\t%s\t%s\n"), buff0, buff1, buff2);%  output each line to Excel
            file.Write(msg, msg.GetLength());
            }
        }
    }
```

I find msg.Format(_T("%s\t%s\t%s\n"), buff0, buff1, buff2); is not executed as I wish. The output Excel file is like
[image]

But it should be 3 elements (0,1,2) in each line according to msg.Format(_T("%s\t%s\t%s\n"), buff0, buff1, buff2);

However file.Write("A\tB\tC\n", 56); is executed as wish.

Anyone knows what's the problem. Thanks very much!

Comment: And when I open the Excel file, it alerts the xls file format and extension mismatch...

Comment: Because what you are writing is not an actual XLS file, but a plain text file. Just because you've used the .xls file extension doesn't make it a valid excel file. You'd need something [like that](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/219/Creating-Excel-Sheets-using-ODBC) to create actual XLS files. But beware of [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46706128/odbc-export-to-excel-fails-under-windows-7-windows-8-x-and-windows-10).

Comment: Excel will try to open this text file as *.xls, it fails, it then tries to opens it as tab delimited *.txt file. You should change the file name to `"d:\\test.txt"` for consistency. Or you can save in *.csv format with comma instead of tab.

Comment: so there is no way to write the list control to an excel file directly? must use ODBC?

Comment: Maybe .csv is the best choice! Thanks a lot to you guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing to file in UTF-16. `msg.GetLength()` returns the number of `wchar_t` in the string, which is half of the total length of what's in the buffer (in this example). If you write `L"12345\n"` in this way, it may show as `" 1 2 3"` in ANSI, the rest of the string is lost.

In `file.Write("A\tB\tC\n", 56)` you assign an arbitrary number, 56, which is larger than the buffer, it happens to work.

You should write to file in ANSI, or change UTF-16 to UTF-8 to preserve Unicode. Example:

```
CStringA u8 = CW2A(_T("A\tB\tC\n"), CP_UTF8);
file.Write(u8, u8.GetLength());

for(...)
{
    buff0 = _T("0"); 
    buff1 = _T("1");
    buff2 = _T("2");
    CString msg;
    msg.Format(_T("%s\t%s\t%s\n"), 
            (LPCTSTR)buff0, (LPCTSTR)buff1, (LPCTSTR)buff2); 
    u8 = CW2A(msg, CP_UTF8);
    file.Write(u8, u8.GetLength());
}
```

Comment: Hi, Barmak. Thank you very much! It works! Appreciate!

Comment: It should be mentioned that `msg.Format(_T("%s\t%s\t%s\n"), buff0, buff1, buff2);` is UB.

Comment: @zett42 Why is it UB?

Comment: `CString` is not a C-style string. You should call `buff0.GetString()` and so on, to get a pointer to a zero terminated character array. Even though `CString` is designed to be binary compatible with C-style strings, this is not (to my knowledge) documented.

Comment: Edit, added `(LPCTSTR)` cast for `CString`

Answer (score 0):

There are excellent libraries that can write nice and feature-rich xlsx Excel files. Like:
http://sourceforge.net/p/simplexlsx/wiki/Home/